# How to find out the confidence level of audio transcription with the Azure SpeechService SDK for Python

Tags: python-3.x, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I am testing the following code to transcribe a long audio, it turns out that I would need to get the confidence level of the transcription result for each word, where at another time it would be possible to check the transcription quality.

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import time


def speech_recognize_continuous_from_file():

    """performs continuous speech recognition with input from an audio file"""
    # <SpeechContinuousRecognitionWithFile>
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=SUBSCRIPTION_KEY, region=REGION)
    speech_config.speech_recognition_language="pt-BR"
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename="file.wav")
    speech_config.enable_dictation()
    speech_config.output_format = speechsdk.OutputFormat(1)
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
    done = False

    def stop_cb(evt):
        """callback that signals to stop continuous recognition upon receiving an event `evt`"""
        print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
        nonlocal done
        done = True

    # Connect callbacks to the events fired by the speech recognizer
    speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZING: {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZED: {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))
    # stop continuous recognition on either session stopped or canceled events
    speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
    speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)
    # Start continuous speech recognition
    speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
    time.sleep(15)
    speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()

speech_recognize_continuous_from_file()
```

I know there is a possibility to get these values with REST API, so far I could not find ways to get this confidence level with Python SDK.

Also I've changed the speech_recognizer output_format to 'detailed' so I could get the  NBest description, but it turns out that when I'm using the start_continuous_recognition method, all of NBest details get suppressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently The detailed output has the Confidence Score to show. It's available in csharp but not in other languages.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console/speech_recognition_samples.cs#L102

Answer (score 0):

It is now supported for python as well. As you have it in your sample code you just need to set the output format to a detailed version:

`speech_config.output_format = speechsdk.OutputFormat(1)`

and you can retrieve the NBest results by checking the `evt.result.json`. An example of NBest results look like this:

[image]